# Android Native crash in tgkill

Tags: android

Suddenly there is this native crash that appeared on our Google play console. Spent a more than a week figuring this out and the answers on other related question doesn't seem to apply to our case.

```
backtrace:


  #00  pc 000000000006b5b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000068a50  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
  #02  pc 0000000000023f68  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
  #03  pc 000000000001c9ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
  #04  pc 0000000000011184  /system/lib64/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+232)
  #05  pc 0000000000033e18  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #06  pc 000000000003454c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
  #07  pc 000000000003b980  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread22dispatchFrameCallbacksEv+212)
  #08  pc 000000000003bb5c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+148)
  #09  pc 0000000000012488  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+272)
  #10  pc 00000000000a4d40  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+116)
  #11  pc 0000000000068258  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
  #12  pc 000000000001dc00  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

This suddenly occurred last April 2. Our last update for the app was February and since then we haven't seen this crash but then it suddenly appeared.

Most users affected are on Android 7.0 and 7.1.

But we also have Android 8.0 users affected with the backtrace a little different.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000071854  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 000000000001e058  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
  #02  pc 0000000000008248  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+328)
  #03  pc 0000000000052430  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread10EglManager11damageFrameERKNS1_5FrameERK6SkRect+320)
  #04  pc 000000000004f9dc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread14OpenGLPipeline4drawERKNS1_5FrameERK6SkRectS8_RKNS0_12FrameBuilder13LightGeometryEPNS0_16LayerUpdateQueueERKNS0_4RectEbRKNS0_15BakedOpRenderer9LightInfoERKNSt3__16vectorINS_2spINS0_10RenderNodeEEENSM_9allocatorISQ_EEEEPNS0_19FrameInfoVisualizerE+76)
  #05  pc 000000000004d7e0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13CanvasContext4drawEv+176)
  #06  pc 000000000004de80  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13CanvasContext14prepareAndDrawEPNS0_10RenderNodeE+192)
  #07  pc 00000000000581ec  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread22dispatchFrameCallbacksEv+220)
  #08  pc 0000000000058494  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+356)
  #09  pc 0000000000011c58  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+280)
  #10  pc 00000000000fd688  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+136)
  #11  pc 000000000006de44  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
  #12  pc 000000000001f9a4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

I've read related questions about this but most thinks that it is caused by the maps library from google but we are not using that.

Here are our dependencies:

```
compile files('libs/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2_jdk5.jar')
compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/restclient.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlwise-1_2.jar')
compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.7.jar')
compile files('libs/joda-time-2.9.4.jar')

//Appsee
compile files('libs/appsee-android-2.3.4.jar')

//Amazon In-App
compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.61.jar')

//Facebook
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'

//Localytics
compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'

//Multidex
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2'

//Helpshift
compile 'com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

//Flurry
compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.0.2@aar'

//Ironsource
compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/adcolonyadapter-4.0.0.jar')
compile 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
compile files('libs/applovinadapter-4.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/hyprmxadapter-4.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/tapjoyadapter-4.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/vungleadapter-4.0.0.jar')
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0'

//Youappi
compile(name:'youappiandroidsdk', ext:'aar')
compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6') {
    transitive = true;

}

//Fyber
compile 'com.fyber:fyber-sdk:8.18.0'

//Rootbeer - check if rooted
compile 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.4'

//Kik
compile 'com.kik:kik-api:1.0.2'

//Twitter
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

//Mopub
compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.18.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'

//Constraint layout
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//MobVista
compile files('libs/mobvista_alphab.jar')
compile files('libs/mobvista_common.jar')
compile files('libs/mobvista_reward.jar')
compile files('libs/mobvista_mvjscommon.jar')
compile files('libs/mobvista_playercommon.jar')
compile files('libs/mobvista_videocommon.jar')

//One by AOL
compile(name:'android-ad-sdk', ext:'aar')

//Baidu
compile(name:'DuappsAd-CW-v1.1.1.0-release', ext:'aar')

//http
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

//google
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.4.2'

//google firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'

//amdroid lifecycle
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Is there someone who also encountered this crash spike on the same date or close? Or have idea which library causes it? Any lead will help. We couldn't reproduce the crash on our side even with the same device that play console say is affected. We also have no clue where the crash happens, if it is on start-up or in the background since our other crash loggers doesn't catch this crash and we only see it on the Google Play Console.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm searching for an answer to this very question, too. So far my best answer that I've seen is that it comes from Google Play-Services Ads.